# Is there a way to fetch class name as a String in designated initializer

Tags: initialization, swift2

Is there any way to get class name as a String in init before calling super.init

I want to create init method for subclass of NSManagedObject so I don't need to create entity every time. This CoreDataManagedObject is an abstract class and all my ManagedObject's need to inherit from it. Now how can I get className in init() as a String?

```
class CoreDataManagedObject: NSManagedObject {

  init() {
    let entityName = <get class name here as a String>
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)!
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)
  }
}

class Company: CoreDataManagedObject {
}
```

I cannot use self before super.init so I wonder if there is another way in init() to fetch info which object is gonna be created. If I'm creating Company object I just want to entityName = "Company".

Comment: Definitely there is some solution, that prevent you from using Class Name before super.init, but if you want to do this one of the solutions can be to have a property with className in any class that you have, and than access it from init:
class CoreDataManagedObject: NSManagedObject {
    var name = "CoreDataManagedObject"
    init() {
        let entityName = name
    }
}

class Company: CoreDataManagedObject {
    var nameN = "Company"
    override var name: String {
        get {
            return nameN
        }
        set {
            nameN = newValue
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a protocol but you would have to add it to all you entity classes:

```
protocol CoreEntityClass 
{
   init(forEntity:String)
}

extension CoreEntityClass
{
   init() 
   {
     self = Self(forEntity:"\(Self.self)")
   }
}

class CoreDataManagedObject:NSManagedObject
{   
   required init(forEntity entityName:String)
   {
     let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)!
     super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)
   }
}


class Company:CoreDataManagedObject, CoreEntityClass 
{
  //...
}
```